# How to eliminate seconds in DateFormat Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display the current DateTime in a Text widget after tapping on a button. The following works, but I'd like to change the format.

I've tried to delete the miliseconds from the DateFormat string, but it seems to not be working since they are rendered anyway
**Current approach**

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  CalendarClient calendarClient = CalendarClient();
  DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
  DateTime endTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));
  TextEditingController _eventName = TextEditingController();

return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(context, showTitleActions: true, minTime: DateTime.now(), maxTime: DateTime(2222, 6, 7), onChanged: (date) {
                        print('change $date');
                      }, onConfirm: (date) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.startTime = date;
                          print('start time $date');
                        });
                      }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Event Start Time',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                    )),
                Text(
                  '$startTime',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(context, showTitleActions: true, minTime: DateTime(2019, 3, 5), maxTime: DateTime(2200, 6, 7),
                          onChanged: (date) {
                        print('end time $date');
                      }, onConfirm: (date) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.endTime = date;
                        });
                      }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Event End Time',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                    )),
                Text(
                  '$endTime',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)), border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.redAccent, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
                controller: _eventName,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.event,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Enter Event title',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                cursorColor: Colors.redAccent,
                cursorRadius: Radius.circular(16.0),
                cursorWidth: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Insert Event',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  calendarClient.insert(
                    _eventName.text,
                    startTime,
                    endTime,
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

YYYY-MM-JJ  HH-MM:00.000

**Question**

How can I remove the :00.000 part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `dateFormat` property but not using it to format date time
should be

```
print('start time ${dateFormat.format(date)}');
```

and

```
Text(
  '${dateFormat.format(startTime)}',
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 18),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [intl: ^0.16.1](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)
For better segmentation of your date and time as of if you want to have date day week name or some other format you can manage easily.

Comment: I am using the latest version of the package